# html tags surrounded with " " not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, string, tags, vue.js

When I am checking with dev tools in chrome I am getting this in my page

```
<span>
 "<b> test data </b>"
</span>
```

The html tags  are not working like this. How can I modify this string so that the html tags will work. The data **`"<b> test data </b>"`** is comming from a $.Ajax request to the server. The **`<b>`** tags are not rendering and I am getting plain text.

```
        var v = new Vue({
    el: ..,
    data : {
        rows: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
     var self = this;
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url:  ...,
           data: {},
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {
          var json_data = JSON.parse(data.d);
         self.rows=json_data
        },
        error: function() {}
        })
}
})
```

I am iterating the data as follows

```
<tr v-for= "row in rows">
  <td>{{row.question}}</td>
<tr>
```

**update**

This seems to be working for me. Can anyone please tell if this code is valid?

```
<tr v-for ="row in rows">
  <td> <span v-html="row.question"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: So what results are you currently getting, and what results do you want?

Comment: the <b> tags are not rendering and I am getting plain text. The <b> tags should work

Comment: Can you `console.log` the raw data coming from the ajax call to ensure it's not coming from the server? And are you using `$e.html(data)` or `$e.text(data)`?

Comment: Could you show the ajax call you are using?

Comment: The code in your update is valid. You could also put the `v-html` on the `td` itself and not have a `span`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In
> order to output real HTML, you will need to use [the `v-html` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

Comment: How can I use v-html with v-for?

Answer (score 2):

If it's coming from a server and you are adding it to the DOM with javascript, you'll want to set `innerHTML` as it will treat it as a DOM object. if you set the span `innerText` it will treat it as a string and the tags will not render correctly.